# Avoid 'read' command stopping for input when no input from stdin

Tags: bash, shell-script, read, stdin

I have a function that takes input from the command line, and, *optionally*, from stdin.  However, it will stop for input when no input stream is specified.

```
#!/bin/bash
somefunc() {
  # output strings on command line.
  while (($#)); do
    echo "$1"
    shift
  done

  # take input from stdin, if it exists.
  declare line
  while read -sr line; do 
    echo "$line"
  done
}

somefunc "$@"
```

This works:

```
$ somefunc "arg1" "arg2" "..." <"/some/file"
```

This does not:

```
$ somefunc "arg1" "arg2" "..."
```

I can get around this problem by using a timeout on the read command (-t 0.0001 for instance), but this seems a bit kludgy and fragile.

Is there a better way of achieving this without using a timeout?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/911168/96588)

Comment: that's not the best solution in my view. can someone else think about this?

Comment: if fact, it's not a solution in any sense for this issue. can you can explain the relevancy?

Answer (score 1):

The bash builtin test with -t should be able to do the job quite well.  `[ -t 0 ]`
There is a good example in this link:

[How to detect if input is from argument, file or terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-to-detect-if-input-is-from-argument-file-or-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to this, and both are equally fast and not kludgy.

This is my preferred solution:

```
  # take input from stdin, if it exists.
  if read -t 0; then
    declare line
    while read -sr line; do 
      echo "$line"
    done
  fi
```

[ -t 0 ] also works:

```
  # take input from stdin, if it exists.
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
    declare line
    while read -sr line; do 
      echo "$line"
    done
  fi
```

Comment: an examination of this issue can be found deep at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495509/why-bash-read-t-0-does-not-see-input

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you add `< /dev/null` at the end of your command which is hanging.

This would feed the command dummy input so that it can move on and not try to mess with your stdin.